# NStimer fire first and then on schedule

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, nstimer, schedule

Is it possible to make a NStimer that fires first when it is initialized and then afterwards on a 0.01 seconds schedule? I have this code..

```
 self.displayTimerTotalTime = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.01
 target:self
 selector:@selector(timerFiredTotalTime:)
 userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.displayTimerTotalTime forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Problem is that the user can stop the timer multiple times and run it again, but this creates a 0.01 delay every time that can cause problems for the user experience. It is not good enough to check for the delay later and remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the [`-fire`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000319-DontLinkElementID_4) method to fire the timer at any time. Just add this after the above code:

```
[self.displayTimerTotalTime fire];
```

Comment: one question tho.. Do you know if the timer 0.01 will wait till the "fire" timer is ended, or will can they cross each other?

Answer (score 0):

You could always call the selector yourself:

```
[self timerFiredTotalTime:self.displayTimerTotalTime];
```